# JDialog - how to change icon

Tags: swing

I want to change icon of the JDialog (to replace standard java cup)
I am able to do that this way:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(OuterClass.class.getResource("fileThatWorks.jpg"));
myJDialog.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Howerver when I replaced `fileThatWorks.jpg` with `image.ico` code stopped working.
I've tried to convert my `image.ico` to `image.jpg` but it didn't nelped.

What's wrong with my approach? Why it works for some *jpg files but doesn't work for *ico files?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to convert .ico to .jpg"--how is that different from your using a JPG file originally?

Comment: original jpg and image.jpg converted from image.ico - are different files. updated description, thanks

Comment: I don't think Java has support for .ico or .bmp files, but .jpg

Comment: You say you have converted image.ico into image.jpg; have you visually checked the resulting jpg after conversion? What converter tool have you used? Also, have you put the right path name in `getResource()`? Note that the path name is case-sensitive (if you package your application into a jar). Finally, if usign a jar-packaged application, did you check that image.jpg was copied into the jar?

Comment: PNG supports image transparency, so you could use a PNG instead of a .ico file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ImageIcon [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) states that the supported types are JPEG & GIF. Not too sure of a workaround for that.

Comment: Since .ico is a windows based file type, I would avoid using them in Java. You would lose the ability to operate on multi-platforms.

Comment: just a fyi, "...(as of 1.3) PNG" is also supported by `java.awt.Image` and also `ImageIcon`