# JDialog - how to set icon that has "transparency"?

Tags: swing

I want to change JDialog icon.
Code below works for *.jpg files, but doesn't work for *.ico files (also refer to my previous question [JDialog - how to change icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285937/jdialog-how-to-change-icon))

```
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Wizard.class.getResource("Picture.jpg"));
    wizardDialog.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Of course I can convert my *.ico file to *.jpg file, but then I will loose transparency.
I want to keep transparency (icon without transparency is very ugly). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a problem with the .ico format. I have never tried to use .ico but rather relied on .png which supports alphatransparency very well. Maybe converting your .ico file to .png will do the trick for you.

Comment: hm how can I convert ico to png? I've tried ms paint, but it said that I will loose transparency

Comment: Heh, we answered almost the same thing at the same time :P

Comment: @javapowered: try something more sophisticated like gimp or paint.net.

Comment: @javapowered : photoshop can handle the .ico file with this plugin http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html

Comment: @Nils Munch: How awesome is that? :D

Comment: succesfully converted using online converter that I googled, that works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Converting your .ico to .png would do the trick. .png has a full alpha channel to store transparency, jpg does not.