# Adding icon to costum JDialog

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to change the icon next to the title of my costum JDialog, but i cant get it to work. It worked this way for a JOptionPane before.

```
private ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader.getInstance();
...
setBounds(100, 100, 603, 419);
setTitle("über CogFit");
new ImageIcon(this.rl.loadImage("gfx/srh_logo_32x32.png"));
```

I already tried this:
[JDialog - how to change icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285937/jdialog-how-to-change-icon)
but it also didnt work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by _you cannot get it work_? Is there any exceptions? Any output?

Comment: everything is ok with the code, no exceptions but it stays the default icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the icon displayed in the tile bar you must use the `JDialog#setIconImage(Image)` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image)